# How to make working login into Laravel 5.+ with JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, token

I'm trying to test a few functions on my Laravel based website. However, I'm having difficulties logging in the website. I've used BlazeMeters Chrome plugin to record my events and save it in jmx file. Was able to do that and imported the file in JMeter. Now at login we are not just examine the email and password, but also a _token variable. This is individual for all visitors. Do I need and if yes, then how can I fetch the token for one user and use that at login time and any other time, when the _token was requested?

Bert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test flow should look like:

1. Open Login Page (usually [HTTP Get Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET))

   - Extract the token from the response using one of JMeter's [Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) (normally people use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) or [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor))
2. Perform Login (usually [HTTP Post Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)) providing credentials and the token from the step 1

The process is known as **correlation** and there is a plenty of information on it over the Internet.

If you want to get things done faster you could consider an alternative way of recording a JMeter test scenario which automatically detects dynamic parameters, generates the relevant post-processors to extract them and store into JMeter Variables and substitutes parameters with the variables so you won't have to do it manually. Check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more details.